# Input of a fucntion with "boolean" return type and "no parameters" in C

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, embedded, driver

```
boolean function(void)
{
   return TRUE;
}
```

Can this function return false during unit testing?

Details:

I am looking at the unit test cases of complex device drivers done in Tessy. By default tessy is setting passing value of `unsigned char function` to "irrelevant". Using this interface, the return value is always `TRUE`

Now one of the previous testers tested this unit by setting interface of `unsigned char function` to "input" and setting it as `FALSE`, this causes return value to `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`.

According to my understanding this test case seems invalid because this function can't take any inputs and will always return true.

Comment: No, it can't. It will not return false in any circumstance.

Comment: if you have access to the code, you can define `TRUE` as `0` or equivalent before this function and then define it back right after it

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What about `#ifdef TRUE \ #undef TRUE \ #define TRUE 0 \ #endif`? :)

Comment: Asthe function cannot return false, a test case assuming it returned false is indeed invalid as that state can never be reached; however, testing the unit internally for robustness and to guard against future errors, can be a good idea.

Comment: Algirdas, the point is that the function is _defined_ as to always return boolean `true`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks, most reasonable answer so far :) Because in unit testing mostly functions are tested as stand alone test objects, As always I made a mistake in description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the function cannot return false, a test case assuming it returned false is indeed invalid as that state can never be reached; however, testing the unit internally for robustness and to guard against future errors, can be a good idea.

But if in any future version, the function will still never return false (i.e. its definition will never change), then using efforts (resources) to test the unit against something that can never happen, is a waste of resources (and money).

Should then in some unforseable future, the function definition *does* change, then it is the process of Change Management to identify any parts affected and re-test those, now including a `false` return value.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a method on a class and it appears in a base class it might be overridden in a derived class like so:

```
 class A
 {
    bool function() // note use of a real C++ type, bool
    {
        return true; // note use of a real C++ bool constant
    }
 }

 class B
 {
    bool function() // C++ doesn't have an @overrides annotation
    {
        return false;
    }
 }

 void main()
 {
   A a;
   B b;
   A & c(b)
   assert(a.function());
   assert(! b.function());
   assert(c.function());  // because function is not virtual
```

---

Alternative way in which you can get a false given the 'fake' boolean:

```
 #define TRUE 0
```

[that's why you should use real types]

---

Edit: I notice your question is tagged [C] as well as [C++].  This answer only applies to C++ (which has classes).